# CSS positioning not working on block level image

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I have a container element that holds an image. I am trying to position the image inside with jquery CSS but for some reason it is not working. The other CSS properties are working, it is only the position props that are not working.

```
<div class="carousel" style="position:absolute;">
    <img src="" style=""/>
    <a class="slideshow-left leftarrow" src="#"/>
    <a class="slideshow-right rightarrow" src="#"/>
    <a class="slideshow-close closecross" src="#"/>
</div>

my_image.css({
    "display" : "inline-block",
    "position" : "absolute",                            
    "top" : "300",
    "left" : "100",
    "width" : "100"
});
```

Any idea why the left and top attributes not working?

Comment: An element is positioned absolute w.r.t to a parent whose position is non-static. Maybe this has to do something with your problem.

Comment: test with: `"top" : "300px",` or just `"top" : 300,` etc...

Comment: Could you please post working fiddle with js, css codes here http://jsfiddle.net/? Parent element may cause the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because none of your `top` and `left` values contain a unit (*`em`/`px`/`%` etc*) inside the quotes

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much didn't understood what kind of jquery method call you are using....but,this works for me...also use `300px` (*note the unit*) instead of `300`

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y7fHv/1/)

```
    $(".carousel >img").css({
    "display": "inline-block",
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "300px",
        "left": "100px",
        "width": "100px"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="carousel" style="position:relative;">
            <img  src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/91e19785a2086f44d56b9897abf4f90f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;" />
            <a  class="slideshow-left leftarrow" src="#" />
            <a  class="slideshow-right rightarrow" src="#" />
            <a  class="slideshow-close closecross" src="#" />
        </div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/K6d9r/